# Organizing and deploying multiple SPAs on the same domain

Tags: reactjs, single-page-application, router

Imagine company `ABC` has two teams developing two SPA apps: `app1`, `app2`

each app has its own `index.html` and associated static assets, for example:
    build/
        index.html
        main.js

This is run from: `host1`. app follows the same conventions

We would like:

- `abc.com/app1` to route to `host1`
- `abc.com/app2` to route to `host2`

Say there is a load balancer setup to perform the routing properly.
What solution do I have for this kind of situation?

I tried to use https://github.com/zeit/serve (suggested by **create-react-app**) but there are tons of problems.

First, `rewritePath` feature does not work (entirely fails to do anything useful)

Second, I tried to put my static assets 1 layer deeper on the host, the request `host1/app1` is a directory listing rather than the `index.html` page

Even after solving these issues through configs, there are still a ton of issues with React Router (SPA router) and authentication callbacks

What is the actual best practice for this scenario? I imagine it is a very common scenario. As I can see AWS's web console uses a similar approach for routing apps

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Basically you want a reverse-proxy like `nginx` to server two different sites at different `URIs`. The SPAs should not know about each other, because it should not concern them how they are reached, it's the job of the reverse proxy.

Basic config for `nginx`:

```
server {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name abc.com;

  location /app1 {

    rewrite /app1(/?(.*)) /$2  break;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:XXXX;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }

  location /app2 {

    rewrite /app2(/?(.*)) /$2  break;

    proxy_pass http://localhost:YYYY;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header Connection "";
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
  }
}
```

Of course this config misses important stuff like `ssl`, `gzip`, `caching` and so on, but it should give you and idea.

In this example, the SPAs could run in two different `docker` containers, reachable by ports `XXXX` and `YYYY`.

Hope this helps,
lgG

Answer (score 0):

What you’re looking for is a reverse proxy. any modern web server can do this including Nginx or Apache. The trick of it will be getting your rewrite routes just right which is what I suspect you’re running into with React.